# Will my website assemblies always run in the same AppDomain together?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, iis-7, appdomain

I have built two different user control libraries to use on my SharePoint 2007 site. One provides user controls for Ecommerce functions, the other for an account dashboard. Both of them are make use of authenticated users/site membership.

So I've built an assembly called WebAccounts.dll which contains all of the basic, common, account functionality such as logging in,  logging out, retrieving member data and storing certain pieces of member data in session. Both the Ecommerce library and account dashboard library reference this account and build on top of it. For instance, both provide their own version of a login/logout control that captures the user credentials, and pass them along to WebAccounts to be authenticated and store the authenticated member object in session.

Where I'm lost is ultimately how IIS creates AppDomains and instances of these libraries. If I place all 3 assemblies in the bin of my SharePoint site, is a user guaranteed to be using instances of the three assemblies contained within the same AppDomain? Or on one page might a user's request process in an AppDomain where only Ecommerce and WebAccounts is loaded, and the next request process in an AppDomain where only dashboard and WebAccounts is loaded?

Point in case: I would like WebAccounts to provide Login and Logout events so that anything that uses the assemblies can perform server-side actions in response. I.E. Can a user be using Ecommerce, which adds some objects to Session State, then click "log out" on a Dashboard user control, which in turn calls Logout() in WebAccounts.dll, fire a "LoggedOut" event in WebAccounts.dll, and be guaranteed the instance of Ecommerce I was using (which has subscribed to the event on application startup) will be able to handle that event to remove its items from Session State? Another example is if WebAccounts defines a static variable, will Ecommerce and Dashboard use that same variable as I navigate between the pages of the site? Since these all run under the same application starting point, the SharePoint site, in the same bin together, it seems like they should all be in the same AppDomain and it should work?

Other concerns are the GAC, and scalability. First, my assemblies are actually in the GAC, because it's a lot easier to use them in SharePoint that way. My expectation would be that loading them from  the GAC instead of the bin wouldn't change the way AppDomains are set up. Second, if we were to move to a server farm, could it still work. Given than we're using SQL based session state, I think that part would work. I know accessing a static variable would break down from request to request because there would be multiple instances of the variable on different servers, but could the variable be reliably set and retrieved by both user control libraries during a single request? Was my WebAccounts assembly just a horrible idea for a web site?

Comment: This is not an IIS issue but a Sharepoint issue. Please retag.

Comment: @usr I have the same questions for a non-SharePoint site. SharePoint just so frequently adds another layer of complexity so I included it.

Answer (score 0):

During normal operations there is one worker process and one app domain for each web site (assuming you are using one web site per app pool - I'm not aware of any reason of not doing that).

This means that all code that is loaded will share the same static variables and the same application state.

During recycling there can be multiple workers and multiple app domains but their contents are structured in the same way.

I don't know how Sharepoint operates. Probably, it runs as a single web site. Therefore, all code that is loaded is hosted in the same app domain.

The litmus test to see whether two libraries share the same app domain is whether they have access to the same `HttpContext.Current`.

The GAC does not play any role here. There is no such thing as "an instance of a DLL". There is just one DLL and it can be loaded into different app domains.

> I know accessing a static variable would break down from request to request because there would be multiple instances of the variable on different servers

That is true.

> but could the variable be reliably set and retrieved by both user control libraries during a single request

During a single request there is only ever one app domain involved in processing it. No exceptions. Whatever code is loaded in that app domain can take part. So as long as Sharepoint decides to load your code (and call it) you're set.

> I would like WebAccounts to provide Login and Logout events so that anything that uses the assemblies can perform server-side actions in response.

The key question is: Is there anything that causes your DLLs to hook up those events? Ensure that that is the case. It is not a concern whether your DLLs are loaded or where. The concern is whether code in them is being called to allow them to subscribe to those events.